# change style of stackpanel childs on mouseover

Tags: c#, wpf

How do i set the style for 2 different controls in a stackpanel on mouseover?
i have the following:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image x:Name="InfoImg" Source="off.png"/>
      <Label x:Name="InfoLabel" Content="OFF"/>
</StackPanel>
```

onMouseOver the stackpanel, i would like to change the image source to

```
<Image x:Name="InfoImg" Source="on.png"/>
```

and the Label text to

```
<Label x:Name="InfoLabel" Content="ON"/>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="YOUR_IMAGE_NAME" Property="Source" Value="on.png"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="YOUR_TEXTBLOCK_NAME" Property="Text" Value="ON"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="off.png"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="OFF"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
</StackPanel>
```

You can add a key to those styles if you want to apply them only to specific Images & TextBlocks among other.

Comment: Hi.. the problem is: the image will only change if the mouse is over the image itself.. and also the label will only change text if the mouse is over it...i need to change both of them (image and label) when mouse is over the STACKPANEL itself (mouse over the container that holds both controls)

Comment: @lebhero edited my post. You need to specify a x:Name on your TextBlock and Image and put them in the TargetName property for this to work